# How to implement tree structure in Node.js with JSON data, and avoid duplicates?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, data-structures

i have some json data from mongoDB like this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "1"
    },
    "name": "A Inc",
    "children": [
       {"$oid": "2"},{"$oid": "3"}],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "2"
    },
    "name": "ACS",
    "children": [{"$oid": "4"}],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "3"
    },
    "name": "ABC Inc",
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
   {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5"
    },
    "name": "Disney",
    "children": [some other ids],
    "kind": "Channel"
  },
...
]
```

I don't know how to create a forest or multiple trees__(but without knowning the root of each tree)__, ideally, I want generate a data structure that using resursive method to link all those data together, But I'm facing a problem which is sometimes it will have duplicated layers, like

[image]
[image]
[image]

Some of the grand children still in children, I want some algorithm to handle this situation, if id is in leaf layer, it won't in upper layer, that means, each id should theoretically appear once.

Below is my current implementation:

```js
const data = require("./nodes.json");

function createTree(data, rootId) {
  const root = data.find((item) => item._id.$oid === rootId);
  if (!root) return null;

  const children = root.children.map((child) => createTree(data, child.$oid));

  return {
    ...root,
    children,
  };
}


function prettyPrint(node, level = 0) {
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(
        `${"  ".repeat(level)} (${child.kind}) ${child.name} ${child._id.$oid}`
      );
      prettyPrint(child, level + 2);
    });
  }
}

const forest = data.map((item) => createTree(data, item._id.$oid));

prettyPrint(forest);
```

The ideal structure would like this, but I don't know if `1`,`2` are root or not, maybe there are some `99` that is the root of `1`,`2`. The only way to know might be build the tree from the data, then find the root from the data structure.

[image]

Comment: I'm puzzled by the data because it seems to indicate that oid 1 and 2 are children of themselves. A tree should be acyclic. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @danh, sorry, my problem, fixed the problem, it's just normal multi tree(forest)

Comment: I think the logic should kind like, after build the tree, we need to read it again, if we can find the id in deeper layer, we delete all the id upper layer to ensure on id is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. To avoid dups, make a copy of the root that you return. A cheesey way to do that is by parsing a stringified object.

**edit** My understanding is the OP aims to find all of the "roots" in the data. These are defined as not having a parent. Find those first, then build the trees recursively under each root...

```js
const dataFromMDB = [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508c1c0b242ff1782ea053"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508cd00b242ff1782ea057"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508cdd0070c5f278bc3183"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b8ce0070c5f278bc319d"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5850b8e10b242ff1782ea087"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851e8340070c5f278bc31c3"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508b0f0b242ff1782ea04c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b7d00b242ff1782ea082"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5850b7e40070c5f278bc319a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851c3470b242ff1782ea092"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585089390b242ff1782ea045"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585089dc0070c5f278bc316a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "585089f60070c5f278bc316b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508a9a0b242ff1782ea04a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508ab40070c5f278bc3177"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508cc20b242ff1782ea056"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b8e10b242ff1782ea087"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a3"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851d5900070c5f278bc31b8"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585301be0070c5f278bc31c4"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5850b7d00b242ff1782ea082"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b7e40070c5f278bc319a"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5bb0070c5f278bc3194"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5a90b242ff1782ea080"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850892b0b242ff1782ea044"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "585089390b242ff1782ea045"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508c0e0070c5f278bc317e"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508c1c0b242ff1782ea053"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508cdd0070c5f278bc3183"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508d5a0070c5f278bc3187"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508d760b242ff1782ea05c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508d810b242ff1782ea05d"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508d8f0070c5f278bc3189"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b5a90b242ff1782ea080"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5bb0070c5f278bc3194"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "583f7169ab44d8cc5ec303ce"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b7e40070c5f278bc319a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b8890070c5f278bc319c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5850b89b0b242ff1782ea085"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851d4be0b242ff1782ea0a2"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5851d4d50070c5f278bc31b4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585089020b242ff1782ea042"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585089f60070c5f278bc316b"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508ab40070c5f278bc3177"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508d990070c5f278bc318a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508dad0b242ff1782ea05f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b89b0b242ff1782ea085"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508ae90070c5f278bc317a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508b0f0b242ff1782ea04c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508bd60b242ff1782ea050"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508ddc0b242ff1782ea062"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851bcc40b242ff1782ea089"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a4"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a3"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a2"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a5"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851c3260070c5f278bc31ab"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5851c3470b242ff1782ea092"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585335280070c5f278bc31c8"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "585088f10070c5f278bc3167"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "585089020b242ff1782ea042"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508b8f0070c5f278bc317c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508dad0b242ff1782ea05f"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851d4d50070c5f278bc31b4"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508c2c0b242ff1782ea054"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508c380070c5f278bc3180"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508dc50070c5f278bc318c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850b5bb0070c5f278bc3194"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "583f7169ab44d8cc5ec303cd"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508db90b242ff1782ea060"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508dc50070c5f278bc318c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a4"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5851d5620b242ff1782ea0a3"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5851d5900070c5f278bc31b8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "584f16710b242ff1782ea040"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Site",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5a382e29b6f4474bb605466b"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a38287ab6f4474bb605465f"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d216381e3b5854db8aa5"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a38287ab6f4474bb6054662"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d216381e3b5854db8aa7"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5878417eb874d4807727aa80"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a38287ab6f4474bb6054661"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d4e7381e3b5854db8aad"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58584e370070c5f278bc31e2"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d216381e3b5854db8aa8"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3963"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d4f1381e3b5854db8aaf"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3965"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d19f381e3b5854db8aa2"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a38287ab6f4474bb6054663"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3961"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a382e28b6f4474bb605466a"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58784131b624487b77dfc100"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d4f1381e3b5854db8ab0"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d216381e3b5854db8aa6"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5b57cd878fff7b2824987a06"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5a38287ab6f4474bb6054660"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5b57cd878fff7b2824987a07"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3964"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3962"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "585849800070c5f278bc31e0"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d4f1381e3b5854db8aae"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d4f1381e3b5854db8ab1"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5941d1e4381e3b5854db8aa4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508bc20070c5f278bc317d"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508bd60b242ff1782ea050"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508c380070c5f278bc3180"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508cb10070c5f278bc3181"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58508cc20b242ff1782ea056"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58508d4f0070c5f278bc3186"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5850af300070c5f278bc3191"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Site",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a4"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b7d00b242ff1782ea082"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "585301be0070c5f278bc31c4"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851d5620b242ff1782ea0a3"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851c3260070c5f278bc31ab"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a3"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5870b242ff1782ea07e"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b8ce0070c5f278bc319d"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b7e40070c5f278bc319a"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b8e10b242ff1782ea087"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b89b0b242ff1782ea085"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a2"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bcc40b242ff1782ea089"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b8890070c5f278bc319c"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851c3470b242ff1782ea092"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5bb0070c5f278bc3194"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851bd140070c5f278bc31a5"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851d4d50070c5f278bc31b4"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5850b5a90b242ff1782ea080"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851d5900070c5f278bc31b8"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "5851d4be0b242ff1782ea0a2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5875a688b874d4807727aa7a"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5875a699b624487b77dfc0f7"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "588805a0b624487b77dfc263"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "588805b7b624487b77dfc265"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "588805b7b624487b77dfc264"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "588805b7b624487b77dfc267"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "588805b7b624487b77dfc266"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5888073bb624487b77dfc273"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "588807d0b624487b77dfc285"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5888081cb624487b77dfc288"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "588a9506b624487b77dfc2c8"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "589112ebb624487b77dfc2fa"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "589113b6b624487b77dfc31b"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5891148db624487b77dfc336"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "589a3281b624487b77dfc343"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "589a32d9b624487b77dfc344"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "589a3e12b624487b77dfc357"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58a255a40bb5cb35020957e7"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58a255b1994a863602070084"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58a4b3e10bb5cb3502095807"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58a4b3e80bb5cb3502095808"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58a4eaa10bb5cb3502095818"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58aa1cd3994a8636020700ca"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58aa1d8a0bb5cb3502095828"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58ab9da3994a863602070104"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58abcde1994a86360207010c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58bdc9ae7ca25aae497a3c78"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58bdc9b97ca25aae497a3c7c"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58bdc9b97ca25aae497a3c79"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58bdc9b97ca25aae497a3c7a"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58bdc9b97ca25aae497a3c7b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c1a0ed92704aa709c4668c"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c1a0ed92704aa709c4668d"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c1fa5d74df84452348fe7d"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c20da774df84452348fea3"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c20da774df84452348feab"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c210fb74df84452348febd"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58c5ed164a4b9ca32bc53fd3"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58e43b33f67c5f75420cc44e"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Site",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c26f67c5f75420cc454"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c26f67c5f75420cc457"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c26f67c5f75420cc455"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43be9f79ce47642fae5c7"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43bb0f67c5f75420cc450"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c00f67c5f75420cc452"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c26f67c5f75420cc456"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "58e43c16f67c5f75420cc453"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58e43c00f67c5f75420cc452"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58ff9b860049d1ba27ff9d90"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "58ff9bdb0049d1ba27ff9d91"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "590131150049d1ba27ff9d98"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "590902a491391c1523bad64e"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5909159c91391c1523bad660"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "590fde37381e3b5854db89cc"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5914eb368ed1755954d6e893"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5914eb368ed1755954d6e895"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "59377642381e3b5854db8a55"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "5937765a381e3b5854db8a56"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596815f12d52383a7ed77c0b"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "596815f12d52383a7ed77c0c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596c36203a45e57a3fa2ed06"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596d47bcb6a2a86ef4d01e38"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596e9108c6acd437948597d6"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "596e9108c6acd437948597d7"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596e9108c6acd437948597d8"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596e9108c6acd437948597da"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "596e9108c6acd437948597d9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596ed4706f8b592916fc3965"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Channel",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "59701b69ea371e1c198c7272"
    },
    "name": "XXXXX", 
    "kind": "Device",
    "children": [
      {
        "$oid": "59701b69ea371e1c198c7273"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// assign the data parent references
// for each node, get its children. for each child, assign
// the child's parent id to the nodeId
const assignLineage = data => {
  data.forEach(node => {
    const nodeId = node._id.$oid;
    node.children.forEach(childId => {
      const child = data.find(el => el._id.$oid == childId);
      if (child) child.parentId = nodeId;
    });
  });
};


const createTree = (data, rootId) => {
  const root = data.find(el => el._id.$oid == rootId);
  if (!root) return null;
    
  let rootCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(root));
  rootCopy.children = rootCopy.children.map(id => {
    const child = createTree(data, id.$oid);
    if (child) child.parentId = rootCopy._id.$oid;
    return child;
  }).filter(el => el);
  return rootCopy;
};


// first assign parent pointers
assignLineage(dataFromMDB)

// roots don't have parents
const roots = dataFromMDB.filter(obj => !obj.parentId)
console.log(`there are ${roots.length} nodes without a parent`)

const forest = roots.map(root => createTree(dataFromMDB, root._id.$oid))
console.log(forest);
```

Comment: Still not work,  let me add some rea data..

Comment: Added 1% of the real data.;

Comment: Just added picture from your code, you can see one ID appears every layer...

Comment: @Yiffany - edited to handle the case where some nodes are absent from the data (probably occurs because we're running on just a sample of the data).  Further edited your data to reduce it in size so that I could submit the post (< 30k)

Comment: I'm just seeing new requirements in edits regarding the structure of the tree.  Will review that now and respond in a bit

Comment: Great thanks, hope now you understand my complication clearer.

Comment: Okay @Yiffany - hopefully that edit is what you're looking for.

Comment: forest is the input array filtered for root nodes, and the result of a filter is another array. an array of roots is what what we typically want to represent a forest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254769/discussion-between-yiffany-and-danh).